# Obter o bit menos significativo de um inteiro no Java

Tags: java, bit

Estou tentando fazer uma manipulação de bits no java, mas estou com um certo problema.

Estou armazenando um número qualquer em um int e tentando obter o bit menos significativo dele, mas não sei como fazer isso.

Por exemplo:

```
int valor = 98;
```

O valor 98 em binário é 1100010 e eu estou tentando obter e guardar em outro int só o 0(110001'0'), e fazer isso com qualquer número independente do tamanho.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Independente de tamanho? Então posso ter uma estrutura de bitagem imposta por mim, que não os tipos padrões primitivos do Java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para conseguir o bit menos significativo, basta fazer a operação `AND` bit a bit do inteiro que você quer obter o bit com o numero 1. Em binário (32 bits) o 1 é representado pelos 31 primeiros bits 0 e o bit menos significativo 1, com o AND, todos os outros bits vão ser zerados.

O código seria:

```
int least_significant = valor & 1;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Begnini.